Sending NavigateToPose action using roslibjs
Setup:

ROS: ROS2 Humble
Nav2: 1.1.16-1jammy.20240830.231501 amd64
ROSLIBJS: 1.4.1
SERVER: express.js

My target is to send this ROS2 CLI action using roslibjs:
ros2 action send_goal /scout_mini/navigate_to_pose nav2_msgs/action/NavigateToPose "pose: {header: {frame_id: map}, pose: {position: {x: -1.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0}, orientation:{x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0, w: 1.0000000}}}"

/scout_mini: this is the namespace of the robot, all the rest is standard.
Here is my implementation on JS:
app.post("/api/send_robot_home", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    let ros = robot_connection(req.user.ip, req.user.port);

    var actionClient = new roslib.ActionClient({
        ros: ros,
        serverName: "/scout_mini/bt_navigator", 
        actionName: "nav2_msgs/action/NavigateToPose",
        timeout: 1500, 
    });

    const goal = new roslib.Goal({
        actionClient,
        goalMessage: {
        pose: {
            header: {
                frame_id: "map"
            },
            pose: {
                position: {
                    x: 7.0,
                    y: 1.0,
                    z: 0.0
                },
                orientation: {
                    x: 0.0,
                    y: 0.0,
                    z: 0,
                    w: 1.0000000
                }
            }
        }

        },
    });

    goal.send(30 * 1000 * 10); 
});

Of course I'm running the navigation stack and rosbridge_server on my robot. Unfortunately this is not working and I'm obtaining the following error:
[ERROR] [1733477821.278466709] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client 341b2031-b36f-4e68-846f-ef6e6935a664] [id: advertise:/scout_mini/bt_navigator/goal:1] advertise: Unable to import msg class NavigateToPoseGoal from package nav2_msgs. Caused by module 'nav2_msgs.msg' has no attribute 'NavigateToPoseGoal'
[INFO] [1733477821.282096005] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client 341b2031-b36f-4e68-846f-ef6e6935a664] Subscribed to /scout_mini/bt_navigator/status
[ERROR] [1733477821.283682975] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client 341b2031-b36f-4e68-846f-ef6e6935a664] [id: subscribe:/scout_mini/bt_navigator/feedback:4] subscribe: Unable to import msg class NavigateToPoseFeedback from package nav2_msgs. Caused by module 'nav2_msgs.msg' has no attribute 'NavigateToPoseFeedback'
[ERROR] [1733477821.284498997] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client 341b2031-b36f-4e68-846f-ef6e6935a664] [id: subscribe:/scout_mini/bt_navigator/result:5] subscribe: Unable to import msg class NavigateToPoseResult from package nav2_msgs. Caused by module 'nav2_msgs.msg' has no attribute 'NavigateToPoseResult'
[ERROR] [1733477821.285051833] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client 341b2031-b36f-4e68-846f-ef6e6935a664] [id: publish:/scout_mini/bt_navigator/goal:6] publish: Cannot infer topic type for topic /scout_mini/bt_navigator/goal as it is not yet advertised

Has anyone implemented something similar using roslibjs? Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks.
Edit: Update the server name and the message error.
